# nvidia-graphics-drivers-173 установить в ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, драйвер, nvidia

Как я понял этот пакет больше не поддерживается, однако есть необходимость установить этот набор драйверов в ubuntu 16.04. Пробовал скачать установочник с сайта nvidia но тот вы даёт ошибку "the distribution-provided pre-install script failed".

Потом после попытки продолжить пишет:

> ERROR: unable to build the NVIDIA kernel module

далее отправляет в лог /var/log/nvidia-installer.log:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Fri Feb  3 17:06:47 2017
installer version: 1.0.7

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

option status:
  license pre-accepted               : false
  update                             : false
  force update                       : false
  expert                             : false
  uninstall                          : false
  driver info                        : false
  precompiled interfaces             : true
  no ncurses color                   : false
  query latest version               : false
  OpenGL header files                : true
  no questions                       : false
  silent                             : false
  no recursion                       : false
  no backup                          : false
  kernel module only                 : false
  sanity                             : false
  add this kernel                    : false
  no runlevel check                  : false
  no network                         : false
  no ABI note                        : false
  no RPMs                            : false
  no kernel module                   : false
  force SELinux                      : default
  no X server check                  : false
  no cc version check                : false
  run distro scripts                 : true
  no nouveau check                   : false
  run nvidia-xconfig                 : false
  sigwinch work around               : true
  force tls                          : (not specified)
  X install prefix                   : (not specified)
  X library install path             : (not specified)
  X module install path              : (not specified)
  OpenGL install prefix              : (not specified)
  OpenGL install libdir              : (not specified)
  utility install prefix             : (not specified)
  utility install libdir             : (not specified)
  installer prefix                   : (not specified)
  doc install prefix                 : (not specified)
  kernel name                        : (not specified)
  kernel include path                : (not specified)
  kernel source path                 : (not specified)
  kernel output path                 : (not specified)
  kernel install path                : (not specified)
  precompiled kernel interfaces path : (not specified)
  precompiled kernel interfaces url  : (not specified)
  proc mount point                   : /proc
  ui                                 : (not specified)
  tmpdir                             : /tmp
  ftp mirror                         : ftp://download.nvidia.com
  RPM file list                      : (not specified)
  selinux chcon type                 : (not specified)

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 173.14.39.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Continue installation 
   anyway? (Answer: Yes)
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="cc".
-> Performing CC version check with CC="cc".
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/build'
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/build'
-> Performing rivafb check.
-> Performing nvidiafb check.
-> Performing Xen check.
-> Cleaning kernel module build directory.
   executing: 'cd ./usr/src/nv; make clean'...
-> Building kernel module:
   executing: 'cd ./usr/src/nv; make module SYSSRC=/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generi
   c/build SYSOUT=/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/build'...
   NVIDIA: calling KBUILD...
   test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (     \
   echo >&2;                            \
   echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";        \
   echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf 
   are missing.";\
   echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix
   it.";    \
   echo >&2 ;                           \
   /bin/false)
   mkdir -p /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/.tmp_ver
   sions ; rm -f /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/.tm
   p_versions/*
   make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14
   .39-pkg1/usr/src/nv
     cc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/.nv.
   o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/include  -I./arch/x86/
   include -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iin
   clude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./includ
   e/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubun
   tu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -f
   no-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-fo
   rmat-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m3
   2 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-bo
   undary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args -Wa,-mtune=ge
   neric32 -ffreestanding -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCO
   NFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_A
   VX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe 
   -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-c
   hecks -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-
   protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-o
   ptimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -Wdeclaration-after-
   statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=im
   plicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes
    -Werror=date-time -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -I/tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173
   .14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv -Wall -Wimplicit -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wformat -Wch
   ar-subscripts -Wparentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wno-multichar -Werror -MD -Wsig
   n-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-error -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DNVRM -DNV_VERSIO
   N_STRING=\"173.14.39\" -UDEBUG -U_DEBUG -DNDEBUG  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)
   =#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(nv)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(nvidia
   )" -c -o /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/.tmp_nv.
   o /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv-linux.h:16:0,
                    from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv.c:13:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/conftest.h:42:2: 
   error: #error acpi_walk_namespace() conftest failed!
    #error acpi_walk_namespace() conftest failed!
     ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/conftest.h:43:2: 
   error: #error acpi_os_wait_events_complete() conftest failed!
    #error acpi_os_wait_events_complete() conftest failed!
     ^
   In file included from include/linux/bitops.h:36:0,
                    from include/linux/kernel.h:10,
                    from include/linux/sched.h:17,
                    from include/linux/utsname.h:5,
                    from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv-linux.h:25,
                    from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv.c:13:

УБРАНО ЧАСТЬ ЛОГА
                                ^
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv.c:13:0:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv-linux.h: At to
   p level:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv-linux.h:126:2:
   error: #error "struct file_operations compile test likely failed!"
    #error "struct file_operations compile test likely failed!"
     ^
   In file included from include/linux/vgaarb.h:34:0,
                    from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv-linux.h:130,
                    from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr

УБРАНО ЧАСТЬ ЛОГА

                   ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/string_32.h:325:46: note: in definition of macro ‘m
   emset’
    #define memset(s, c, count) __builtin_memset(s, c, count)
                                                 ^
   include/linux/highmem.h:205:16: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used i
   n arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
      memset(kaddr + start2, 0, end2 - start2);
                   ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/string_32.h:325:46: note: in definition of macro ‘m
   emset’
    #define memset(s, c, count) __builtin_memset(s, c, count)
                                                 ^
   In file included from include/acpi/platform/acenv.h:174:0,
                    from include/acpi/acpi.h:56,
                    from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv-linux.h:209,
                    from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv.c:13:
   include/acpi/platform/aclinux.h: At top level:
   include/acpi/platform/aclinux.h:52:2: error: #error "Please don't include <a
   cpi/acpi.h> directly, include <linux/acpi.h> instead."
    #error "Please don't include <acpi/acpi.h> directly, include <linux/acpi.h>
   instead."
     ^
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv-linux.h:210:0,
                    from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv.c:13:
   include/acpi/acpi_drivers.h:94:43: warning: ‘struct acpi_pci_root’ decla
   red inside parameter list
    struct pci_bus *pci_acpi_scan_root(struct acpi_pci_root *root);
                                              ^
   include/acpi/acpi_drivers.h:94:43: warning: its scope is only this definitio
   n or declaration, which is probably not what you want
   In file included from /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv/nv.c:13:0:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv-linux.h:217:4:
   warning: "NV_ACPI_WALK_NAMESPACE_ARGUMENT_COUNT" is not defined [-Wundef]
      (NV_ACPI_WALK_NAMESPACE_ARGUMENT_COUNT == 6)
       ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv-linux.h:219:8:
   warning: "NV_ACPI_WALK_NAMESPACE_ARGUMENT_COUNT" is not defined [-Wundef]
    #elif (NV_ACPI_WALK_NAMESPACE_ARGUMENT_COUNT == 7)
           ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv-linux.h:225:2:
   error: #error "NV_ACPI_WALK_NAMESPACE_ARGUMENT_COUNT value unrecognized!"
    #error "NV_ACPI_WALK_NAMESPACE_ARGUMENT_COUNT value unrecognized!"
     ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv-linux.h:230:4:
   warning: "NV_ACPI_OS_WAIT_EVENTS_COMPLETE_ARGUMENT_COUNT" is not defined [-W
   undef]
      (NV_ACPI_OS_WAIT_EVENTS_COMPLETE_ARGUMENT_COUNT == 1)
       ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv-linux.h:233:8:
   warning: "NV_ACPI_OS_WAIT_EVENTS_COMPLETE_ARGUMENT_COUNT" is not defined [-W
   undef]
    #elif (NV_ACPI_OS_WAIT_EVENTS_COMPLETE_ARGUMENT_COUNT == 0)
           ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c: In function
   ‘nv_kern_read_text_file’:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c:692:12: erro
   r: void value not ignored as it ought to be
        return seq_puts(s, s->private);
               ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c: In function
   ‘nv_kern_ioctl’:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c:2646:26: war
   ning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-com
   pare]
                if (arg_size < (sizeof(*ci) * num_nv_devices))
                             ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c: In function
   ‘nv_kern_unlocked_ioctl’:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c:2749:30: err
   or: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’
        return nv_kern_ioctl(file->f_dentry->d_inode, file, cmd, i_arg);
                                 ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c: In function
   ‘nv_kern_compat_ioctl’:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c:2758:30: err
   or: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’
        return nv_kern_ioctl(file->f_dentry->d_inode, file, cmd, i_arg);
                                 ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c: In function
   ‘nv_kern_read_text_file’:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c:693:1: warni
   ng: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c: In function
   ‘nv_kern_unlocked_ioctl’:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c:2750:1: warn
   ing: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c: In function
   ‘nv_kern_compat_ioctl’:
   /tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.c:2759:1: warn
   ing: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
   scripts/Makefile.build:258: ошибка выполнения рецепта
   для цели «/tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv
   /nv.o»
   make[3]: *** [/tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv/nv.
   o] Ошибка 1
   Makefile:1396: ошибка выполнения рецепта для це\D0
   \BBи «_module_/tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/src/nv»
   make[2]: *** [_module_/tmp/selfgz1728/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1/usr/sr
   c/nv] Ошибка 2
   NVIDIA: left KBUILD.
   nvidia.ko failed to build!
   Makefile:239: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цел
   и «module»
   make[1]: *** [module] Ошибка 1
   makefile:54: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цел\D0
   \B8 «module»
   make: *** [module] Ошибка 2
-> Error.
ERROR: Unable to build the NVIDIA kernel module.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
       '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions
       on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux
       driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Comment: Если очень сильно нужен именно этот пакет (непонятно правда почему), то Вам придется пофиксить все те ошибки в с/с++ коде.

Comment: можно попытаться подключить старый репозиторий от Ubuntu 14.04